# Cisco 2911 - Password Recovery Functionality Disabled. Need to Reset to defaults

Tags: password-recovery, cisco-ios

**EDIT- The solution is to use a different IOS version on a newly formatted flash card. This forces the config out of the router due to an IOS mismatch. You will be free to do any configuration from here on out because the router will be wiped.**

I am attempting to recover my 2911 router. I wiped its config and it came back up asking for an enable password. It should have the cisco/cisco passwords and it should give you the option to change them. It is as though this was skipped. I thought this would be no big deal but it seems to have effectively bricked my router. Removing the flash results in a boot loop like seen below:

```
System Bootstrap, Version 15.0(1r)M14, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 2011 by cisco Systems, Inc.

Total memory size = 512 MB - On-board = 512 MB, DIMM0 = 0 MB
Field Upgradeable ROMMON Integri_________________
ROM: Digitally Signed Release Software
CISCO2911/K9 platform with 524288 Kbytes of main memory
Main memory is configured to 72/-1(On-board/DIMM0) bit mode with ECC enabled


Upgrade ROMMON initialized
PASSWORD RECOVERY FUNCTIONALITY IS DISABLED
Compact Flash0: Not present

System Bootstrap, Version 15.0(1r)M14, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 2011 by cisco Systems, Inc.

Total memory size = 512 MB - On-board = 512 MB, DIMM0 = 0 MB
Field Upgradeable ROMMON Integri_________________
ROM: Digitally Signed Release Software
CISCO2911/K9 platform with 524288 Kbytes of main memory
Main memory is configured to 72/-1(On-board/DIMM0) bit mode with ECC enabled


Upgrade ROMMON initialized
PASSWORD RECOVERY FUNCTIONALITY IS DISABLED
Compact Flash1: Not present

System Bootstrap, Version 15.0(1r)M14, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 2011 by cisco Systems, Inc.

Total memory size = 512 MB - On-board = 512 MB, DIMM0 = 0 MB
Field Upgradeable ROMMON Integri_________________
ROM: Digitally Signed Release Software
CISCO2911/K9 platform with 524288 Kbytes of main memory
Main memory is configured to 72/-1(On-board/DIMM0) bit mode with ECC enabled


Upgrade ROMMON initialized
PASSWORD RECOVERY FUNCTIONALITY IS DISABLED
Compact Flash0: Not present
```

Also trying to break at boot doesn't appear to do anything. I am using putty and the break sequence should be Ctrl/Break. Looking at putty's log shows that it is in fact sending a break sequence.

If I allow the router to boot it will try and tftp to the 255.255.255.255 address, a clear sign that it has no configuration. My question is if there is a way to reset the router, or if there is a configuration file that I can drop onto the flash that will allow me to boot to an actual configuration.

As always, any help is greatly appreciated.

Very Respectfully,

Adam Walker

Comment: TAC's suggestion seems to be to RMA a device. This is great if there is a service contract for the device. I am hoping that someone out there knows of something to do to solve this issue. I find it hard to believe that Cisco really expects customers to RMA a perfectly good piece of gear just because they locked themselves out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not experienced this myself but it seems that if you hit the ctrl/break at just the right moment it should allow you to reset to factory default according to this link (which is for a much older ios and router);

http://www.tunnelsup.com/recovering-the-password-when-no-service-password-recovery-is-enabled-on-a-router

Although Ivan Peplnjk reckons there might not be a way to recover from this under certain circumstances once Password Recovery is disabled...

http://blog.ipspace.net/2007/12/recovering-from-disabled-password.html

... for the 3600, Cisco recommends you stick on a new IOS image on on the flash card.

www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/routers/3600-series-multiservice-platforms/46104-no-service-pswdrec.html#risks

Hope this helps.

regards,
Gerry

Comment: Technically this is correct. However it seems to have been disabled in my IOS version.